# summing last entry from pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv like below.

```
a,b,c,d
A,A1,10,B1
A,A1,20,B1
A,A1,30,B1
A,A1,10,B4
A,A1,20,B4
A,A1,10,B5
A,A1,10,B6
B,A2,10,B7
B,A2,20,B1
B,A2,100,B1
```

I want to take the last line of each group and sum the column `c` for each 'a'.

I am able to take last using`.last()` but stuck at doing the sum per 'a' where a is the first `groupby` criteria

```
>>> tmp.groupby(['a','b','d']).nth(-1)
           c
    a b  d      
    A A1 B1   30
         B4   20
         B5   10
         B6   10
    B A2 B1  100
         B7   10
    >>> tmp.groupby(['a','b','d']).nth(-1)['c'].sum()
    180
```

Instead of 180 I need 70, (sum of group A) and 110 (sum of group B)

I think grouping is lost when using last() or nth(-1)

Comment: editing the question. I think i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) with `level=0` or another `groupby` by first level with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = tmp.groupby(['a','b','d'])['c'].nth(-1).sum(level=0)
print (df)
a
A     70
B    110
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df = tmp.groupby(['a','b','d'])['c'].nth(-1).groupby(level=0).sum()
print (df)
a
A     70
B    110
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Same with `last`:

```
df = tmp.groupby(['a','b','d'])['c'].last().sum(level=0)
print (df)
a
A     70
B    110
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df = tmp.groupby(['a','b','d'])['c'].last().groupby(level=0).sum()
print (df)
a
A     70
B    110
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: wow @jezrael you are an aspiration. 
Chcem sa stať ako vy môj priateľ

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].last()
```

returns

```
a  b 
A  A1     20
   A2    100
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: sorry i made a mistake while posting, I have corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `drop_duplicates` and then `groupby`

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['a', 'b','d'], take_last=True).groupby('a')['c'].sum()

Out[104]: 
a
A     70
B    110
```